# Why am i entering into an infinite loop when partitioning a linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, partitioning, partition

This is a common problem of partitioning a linked list into two parts. The list with nodes smaller than x will come first and the list of nodes larger than x will come after.

My question is - why do i need to set after.next to null after creating my two separate linked lists? Without setting it to null, I enter an infinite loop when trying to print this list.
My debugger shows that before_head.next has a never-ending list of nodes attached to it...

```
public Node partition(Node head, int x){
  Node before_head=new Node(0);
  Node before=before_head;
  Node after_head=new Node(0);
  Node after=after_head;

  while(head != null){
    if(head.val < x){
      before.next=head;
      before=before.next;
    else{
      after.next=head;
      after=after.next;
     }
    head=head.next;
   }

   after.next=null;
   before.next=after_head;

   return before_head.next;
}
```

Comment: The node at the end of a list always has a `null` next pointer. In a single list of nodes, only one node will have a `null` next pointer. When those same nodes are rearranged into two lists, two nodes must have `null` next pointers.

Comment: What do you think `after.next` will be equal to, if you don't set it to null? Did you try to check that, for example by using a debugger? In general, what is your understanding of how linked lists work - specifically, when the `.next` of a node is null, what does that *mean*?

Answer (score 1):

> why do i need to set after.next to null after creating my two separate linked lists?

The last node of a linked list doesn't have a next node.  In a linked list representation such as yours, that takes the form of the last node's `next` reference being null.

You are rearranging the existing nodes of the list by changing their `next` references.  At the end of that process, `after` is a reference to the last node, therefore its `next` reference needs to be null.  If it was also the last node in the original order then all is well -- its `next` reference is already null.  If `after` *was not* the last node in the original order, however, then `after.next` will refer to one of the other nodes until you set it null.  And whatever other node that is, it comes before `after` in the new order, forming a loop.

---

Note also that

> ```
>     before.next=after_head;
> ```

appears to be wrong.  `after_head` is the dummy head node of the second partition, so you do not want to include it in the new list.  I think you want

```
    before.next = after_head.next;
```